# paymentQueue:upddatedDownloads isn't being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm building an app that uses in-app purchases with content hosted at Apple. I am able to call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];` and the content correctly downloads to the `/Library/Caches/` directory inside the app. However, during the download, I am unable to get updates on the status of the download, because `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray<SKDownload *> *)downloads` is not being called.

I am using [IAPHelper, an open source wrapper for the IAP API](https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper), to manage in-app purchasing, and I put the `paymentQueue:updatedDownloads` method in the [`IAPHelper.m`](https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper/blob/master/IAPHelper/IAPHelper.m) file. I also tried having `paymentQueue:updatedDownloads` with the code for the Store View Controller, but had the same results.

Any help would be appreciated and I will gladly post some code if necessary (I wasn't sure what code would be helpful, if any).

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody knows what IAPHelper or IAPHelper.m.

Comment: @ElTomato my bad, I'll edit it in. It's an open source wrapper for the IAP API. https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper

Answer (score 0):

In IAPHelper, the code

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue])
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

runs before the code that unlocks content. You have to move it to run *after* the content finishes being downloaded or fails to download.